# MockServer as Socks proxy not working with curl

Tags: java, proxy, mocking, socks, mockserver

I started a [MockServer](https://www.mock-server.com/proxy/configuring_sut.html#socks_proxy) using

```
java -jar mockserver-netty-5.10.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar -serverPort 1080
```

Now if i do (no sock proxy)

```
curl https://www.google.com
```

it work html get printed

But If i do (with socks proxy)

```
 curl --socks5-hostname localhost:1080 https://www.google.com
```

The curl request just stuck forever.

My expectation is  to use `MockServer` as a Sock proxy

**What am i doing wrong?**

---

PS: If i use MockServer as a http proxy is works fine, So what am i doing wrong with `sock`

```
curl -k --proxy localhost:1080 https://www.google.com   this works
```